# Apache CXF 2.7.7 WS-Adressing fails

Tags: java, cxf, soap-client

I am trying to use a CXF WSDL first generated client to call a mock service in SOAP UI.  The WSDL i am using has policy defined as:

```
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="addressing-policy" wsdl:required="true">
        <wsam:Addressing>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <wsam:AnonymousResponse/>
                <wsam:MessageId/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </wsam:Addressing>
    </wsp:Policy>
```

when i invoke my client, i see the ws-Addressing headers in SOAP UI as in:

```
   <soap:Header>
      <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.cablelabs.com/namespaces/safi/wsdl/cip/opUpdateNotice/msgUpdateNotice</Action>
      <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:61e13403-0270-40c8-800a-618007f1a2e4</MessageID>
      <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://localhost:8088/mockbdCIP-UPDATE-SOAP12HTTP</To>
      <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
         <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
      </ReplyTo>
   </soap:Header>
```

and in SOAP UI i see the response being sent as:

```
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
      <wsa:Action>http://www.cablelabs.com/namespaces/safi/wsdl/cip/opUpdateNotice/msgUpdateResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:RelatesTo RelationshipType="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/reply">urn:uuid:635f6d1c-fdb6-423b-9713-e1afe0bbd26e</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsa:MessageID>uuid:a0e5dde0-f02d-42d4-9bda-51fa7b5506a4</wsa:MessageID>
   </soap:Header>
```

in the console i see CXF throwing the following exception:

> Caused by: org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: These policy
>   alternatives can not be satisfied: 
>   {http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata}AnonymousResponse
>   {http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata}MessageId  at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AssertionInfoMap.checkEffectivePolicy(AssertionInfoMap.java:179)
>   ~[cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]   at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.handle(PolicyVerificationInInterceptor.java:101)
>   ~[cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]   at
>   org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.AbstractPolicyInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractPolicyInterceptor.java:44)
>   ~[cxf-rt-ws-policy-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]   at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>   ~[cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:835)
>   ~[cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1606)
>   ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1502)
>   ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309)
>   ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]     at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
>   ~[cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:627)
>   ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]     at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
>   ~[cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>   ~[cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
>   ~[cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
>   ~[cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
>   ~[cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
>   ~[cxf-api-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]    at
>   org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
>   ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]     at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
>   ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.7.7.jar:2.7.7]  ... 42 common frames omitted

Anyone have ideas as to how to fix this?